# Tidying up the data (Remove br and slashes)

Tags: php, mysql

I am redesigning a new website and my database table need tidying up a bit.

In the mysql table, I have a data look like this for example:

```
text text text text - he\'s text text text he\'s text text
text couldn\'t text text.<br /><br />\"I\'m text text
text text. We\'re text <br /><br />text text
```

I need to remove all the slashes () and remove all the 
. What the best way doing this?

From now on I will use mysql_real_escape_string() when adding data. To view use

```
nl2br()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that magic_quotes_gpc is off, it's good practice. You can always use parse your database and reinsert it all.

str_replace is right but don't use it if the data has been escaped, use stripslashes on the data.

```
<?php
    $row = array(
        1 => 'stripslashes removes any unwanted \\\\',
        2 => 'it\'s easy but annoying but we must do it!'
    );
    foreach ($row as $key=>$record) {
        $escaped[$key] = stripslashes($record);
    }
    echo $escaped[1].'<br />';
    echo $escaped[2];
?>
```

Outputs:

> stripslashes removes any unwanted \
>
> it's easy but annoying but we must do it!

Then re-insert it.

Comment: Thank you. Something bothering my mind. If I use a texteditor like TinyMCE for example. How does that deal with break line / new line?

Comment: They will automatically insert the <br /> instead of calling nl2br(). Some may actually use \r\n which is standard and calling nl2br() will fix the output. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use str_replace to remove that

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the extra slashes.

To remove the <br /> tags, do you want to replace them with newline characters? If you've used nl2br, all your <br />s will still have their new lines characters. If you didn't use nl2br, you'd need something like this, using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = str_replace("<br />", "\r\n", $text);
```